# WinForm Touch Events Cefsharp

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

I have an issue with Winforms and touch inputs via a Microsoft Surface tablet. I know that winforms does not support touch input, but maybe there is something there can be done about this. So in my Winforms application i have a Form with two controls. A simple List Box and CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser Control.

When I open the application the HTML is loaded and everything works fine with normal mouse input. I can click the textboxes and I can type. But when i do the same thing with touch controls on a MS Surface it seems the the ChromiumWebBrowser Control dows not get focus. The HTML Textboxes inside the Browser have focus, but the ChromiumWebBrowser Control does not. So whem i type, no input is send to the textboxes.

I tried to set focus manually whit C# in winforms, but those click events do not get fired in touch mode except for the Enter event. But this is fired only once. So i dont know how to get around this.

The user needs to be able to click outside the Browser Controle and do something there and then get back to the Browser and type into those textboxes.

Maybe someone had a similar issue and knows a workaround. If other Info is needed, please tell me.
Here is a gif to illustrate, hope it helps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J0EZ.gif

Thanks

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var asForm = System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.FromHandle(this.Handle);

        wbMap = initBrowser();

        this.panel1.Enabled = true;
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(wbMap);

        wbMap.FrameLoadEnd += WbMap_FrameLoadEnd;
        wbMap.Click += WbMap_Click;
        wbMap.Enter += WbMap_Enter;
        wbMap.MouseClick += WbMap_MouseClick;
        wbMap.DoubleClick += WbMap_DoubleClick;
        wbMap.Leave += WbMap_Leave;
        wbMap.LostFocus += WbMap_LostFocus;
        wbMap.GotFocus += WbMap_GotFocus;
        wbMap.PreviewKeyDown += WbMap_PreviewKeyDown;
    }

    private ChromiumWebBrowser initBrowser()
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser wbMap = new ChromiumWebBrowser();

        BrowserSettings browserSettings = new BrowserSettings();
        browserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
        browserSettings.UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
        wbMap.BrowserSettings = browserSettings;

        wbMap.LoadHtml("<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\" /><title></title></head><body><input type=\"text\"><input /></body></html>");
        wbMap.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        return wbMap;
    }

    private void WbMap_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("QGIS_WbMap_FrameLoadEnd");
    }
```

Comment: Forgot to Mention, the events handlers only do console output like the WbMap_FrameLoadEnd handler, so i did not add them to the text.

Comment: What version are you using? What OS? The WinForms version should support touch input just fine. You won't get the events as chromium doesn't propagate the messages. How does the minimal example behave when using the address field and switching to the browser? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: See also https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#multithreadedmessageloop

Comment: Its Windows 10. The Winforms Version is .NET 4.5.2. I will try the MinimalExample and let you know.

Comment: Make sure you have an app.manifest that includes windows 10 compatibility https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/cefsharp/95/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/app.manifest#L55